# Disable button untill all fields are cleared

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a simple contact form where I add custom validation aside from requiring all fields like email format, numbers for contact number and only letters for name. The validations are working but my problem is how to disable the button if all fields are not cleared.

what I've done right now is disabled the button on default and when one field is cleared the button is enabled even the others fields are empty.

The button must enable if the all fields are cleared from the validations.

Hope you help me.

Thanks.

```js
// form validation
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('form .form-control').keyup(function () {
    let formBtn = true;
        $(this).each(function () {

            if ($(this).val().length === 0) {
                $(this).closest('.form-group').find('span').addClass('text-warning').text('this is a required field');
                formBtn = true;
            } else {
            formBtn = false;
                $(this).closest('.form-group').find('span').removeClass().text('');
                // CHECK IF EMAIL FORMAT IS VALID
                if ($(this).attr('name') == 'email') {
                    if (!validateEmail($(this).val())) {
                        $(this).closest('.form-group').find('span').addClass('text-warning').text('invalid email format');
                    }
                }

                if ($(this).attr('name') == 'name') {
                    if (!validateName($(this).val())) {
                        $(this).closest('.form-group').find('span').addClass('text-warning').text('Only letters, spacing, hypen(-) and period are allowed.');
                    }
                }

                if ($(this).attr('name') == 'contactNumber') {
                    if (!validateContactNumber($(this).val())) {
                        $(this).closest('.form-group').find('span').addClass('text-warning').text('Only Numbers are allowed.');
                    } else if (validateContactNumber($(this).val()) == "invalidLength") {
                        $(this).closest('.form-group').find('span').addClass('text-warning').text('9-15 numbers are allowed.');
                    }
                }
            }
    $(this).closest('form').find('button').prop('disabled',formBtn);
        });
    });


    // VALIDATE NAME
    function validateName(name) {
        var regex = /^[a-zA-Z-.\s]*$/;
        if (regex.test(name)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    // VALIDATE EMAIL
    function validateEmail(email) {
        var regex = /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@([A-Z0-9-]+\.)+[A-Z]{2,4}$/i;
        if (regex.test(email)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    // VALIDATE PHONE NUMBER
    function validateContactNumber(number) {
        var numValid = /^[0-9]+$/;
        var lenValid = /^.{9,15}$/;
        if (numValid.test(number)) {
            if (lenValid.test(number)) {
                return true;
            }else{
                return 'invalidLength';
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

```css
label{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 6px;
    letter-spacing: .025em;
    color: #2A363B;
}
.form-group span{
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 11px;
}
.form-control{
    padding: 12px 25px 12px 25px !important;
    line-height: 24px !important;
    border-radius: 0;
    font-weight: 400;
    height: auto;
    border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
    box-shadow: none;
    transition: .3s ease-in-out;
    background-color: #fcfcfc;
    color: #2A363B;
}
.form-control:focus {
    border-color: rgba(30, 30, 40, .5);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 4px rgba(30, 30, 40, .3);
}
.btn{
    padding: 14px 30px;
    border-radius: 0;
}
.btn-default{
    background-color: #2A363B;
    border: 1px solid #2A363B;
    color: #FFF;
    transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}
.btn-default:focus,
.btn-default:hover{
    background-color: #2A363B;
    border: 1px solid #2A363B;
    color: #FFF;
    opacity: 0.7 !important;
}
.btn[disabled]{
    background-color: #FFF;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    color: #222;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-6">
        <form class="form-horizontal" autocomplete="off" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="subject" class="control-label">Subject</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="subject" name="subject">
                <span></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name" class="control-label">Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name">
                <span></span>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="email" class="control-label">Email</label>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email">
                        <span></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="contactNumber" class="control-label">Contact Number</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="contactNumber" name="contactNumber">
                        <span></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="message" class="control-label">Message</label>
                <textarea name="message" id="message" cols="30" rows="10" class="form-control" name="message"></textarea>
                <span></span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-4">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-block" name="contactBtn" disabled >SUBMIT</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: by default disable the button in html code and enable the button once validations are done.

Comment: You can add required attribute in all the inputs, this is the easiest and best workaround.

Comment: take length of input fields and declare variable count=0; every time if a field is clear, add 1 to counter (also subtract in reverse case). if the count==lengthOfInputField{button->visible}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('form .form-control').keyup(function() {
        let formBtn = true;
        $(this).each(function() {

            if ($(this).val().length === 0) {
                $(this).closest('.form-group').find('span').addClass('text-warning').text('this is a required field');
                formBtn = true;
            } else {
                //  formBtn = false;
                $(this).closest('.form-group').find('span').removeClass().text('');
                // CHECK IF EMAIL FORMAT IS VALID
                if ($(this).attr('name') == 'email') {
                    if (!validateEmail($(this).val())) {
                        $(this).closest('.form-group').find('span').addClass('text-warning').text('invalid email format');
                    }
                }

                if ($(this).attr('name') == 'name') {
                    if (!validateName($(this).val())) {
                        $(this).closest('.form-group').find('span').addClass('text-warning').text('Only letters, spacing, hypen(-) and period are allowed.');
                    }
                }

                if ($(this).attr('name') == 'contactNumber') {
                    if (!validateContactNumber($(this).val())) {
                        $(this).closest('.form-group').find('span').addClass('text-warning').text('Only Numbers are allowed.');
                    } else if (validateContactNumber($(this).val()) == "invalidLength") {
                        $(this).closest('.form-group').find('span').addClass('text-warning').text('9-15 numbers are allowed.');
                    }
                }

                var len = $('input[type=text],textarea').filter(function() {
                    return $(this).val().length == 0
                }).length;

                var warlen = $('.text-warning').filter(function() {
                    return $(this).text().length > 0
                }).length;

                if (len == 0 && warlen == 0) {
                    formBtn = false;
                }

            }
            $(this).closest('form').find('button').prop('disabled', formBtn);
        });
    });


    // VALIDATE NAME
    function validateName(name) {
        var regex = /^[a-zA-Z-.\s]*$/;
        if (regex.test(name)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    // VALIDATE EMAIL
    function validateEmail(email) {
        var regex = /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@([A-Z0-9-]+\.)+[A-Z]{2,4}$/i;
        if (regex.test(email)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    // VALIDATE PHONE NUMBER
    function validateContactNumber(number) {
        var numValid = /^[0-9]+$/;
        var lenValid = /^.{9,15}$/;
        if (numValid.test(number)) {
            if (lenValid.test(number)) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return 'invalidLength';
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/6xyn4taw/)

Answer (score 1):

You can't true your button value on validating of single textbox or single text area you need to validate your whole form and then have to enable your button. Your logic for enabling and disabling button doesn't make any sense.

```js
// form validation
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('form .form-control').keyup(function () {
    let formBtn = true;
        $(this).each(function () {

            if ($(this).val().length === 0) {
                $(this).closest('.form-group').find('span').addClass('text-warning').text('this is a required field');
                
            } else {
            
                $(this).closest('.form-group').find('span').removeClass().text('');
                // CHECK IF EMAIL FORMAT IS VALID
                if ($(this).attr('name') == 'email') {
                    if (!validateEmail($(this).val())) {
                        $(this).closest('.form-group').find('span').addClass('text-warning').text('invalid email format');
formBtn = true;

                    }
                    else
                        formBtn = false;
                }

                if ($(this).attr('name') == 'name') {
                    if (!validateName($(this).val())) {
                        $(this).closest('.form-group').find('span').addClass('text-warning').text('Only letters, spacing, hypen(-) and period are allowed.');
                        formBtn = true;
                    }
                    else
                        formBtn = false;
                }

                if ($(this).attr('name') == 'contactNumber') {
                    if (!validateContactNumber($(this).val())) {
                        $(this).closest('.form-group').find('span').addClass('text-warning').text('Only Numbers are allowed.');
                    } else if (validateContactNumber($(this).val()) == "invalidLength") {
                        $(this).closest('.form-group').find('span').addClass('text-warning').text('9-15 numbers are allowed.');
formBtn = true;
                    }
                    else
                    formBtn = false;
                }
            }
$('input[type=text],textarea').each(function () {

            if ($(this).val().length === 0) {
                formBtn = true;
            }
        });
    $(this).closest('form').find('button').prop('disabled',formBtn);
        });
    });


    // VALIDATE NAME
    function validateName(name) {
        var regex = /^[a-zA-Z-.\s]*$/;
        if (regex.test(name)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    // VALIDATE EMAIL
    function validateEmail(email) {
        var regex = /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@([A-Z0-9-]+\.)+[A-Z]{2,4}$/i;
        if (regex.test(email)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    // VALIDATE PHONE NUMBER
    function validateContactNumber(number) {
        var numValid = /^[0-9]+$/;
        var lenValid = /^.{9,15}$/;
        if (numValid.test(number)) {
            if (lenValid.test(number)) {
                return true;
            }else{
                return 'invalidLength';
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

```css
label{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 6px;
    letter-spacing: .025em;
    color: #2A363B;
}
.form-group span{
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 11px;
}
.form-control{
    padding: 12px 25px 12px 25px !important;
    line-height: 24px !important;
    border-radius: 0;
    font-weight: 400;
    height: auto;
    border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
    box-shadow: none;
    transition: .3s ease-in-out;
    background-color: #fcfcfc;
    color: #2A363B;
}
.form-control:focus {
    border-color: rgba(30, 30, 40, .5);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 4px rgba(30, 30, 40, .3);
}
.btn{
    padding: 14px 30px;
    border-radius: 0;
}
.btn-default{
    background-color: #2A363B;
    border: 1px solid #2A363B;
    color: #FFF;
    transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}
.btn-default:focus,
.btn-default:hover{
    background-color: #2A363B;
    border: 1px solid #2A363B;
    color: #FFF;
    opacity: 0.7 !important;
}
.btn[disabled]{
    background-color: #FFF;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    color: #222;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-6">
        <form class="form-horizontal" autocomplete="off" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="subject" class="control-label">Subject</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="subject" name="subject">
                <span></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name" class="control-label">Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name">
                <span></span>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="email" class="control-label">Email</label>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email">
                        <span></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="contactNumber" class="control-label">Contact Number</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="contactNumber" name="contactNumber">
                        <span></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="message" class="control-label">Message</label>
                <textarea name="message" id="message" cols="30" rows="10" class="form-control" name="message"></textarea>
                <span></span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-4">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-block" name="contactBtn" disabled >SUBMIT</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: doesn't work sir, it enables even the data is invalid

Comment: @user123 actually you asked earlier check empty fields not validation but now both are done

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add required attribute. This is the best easiest workaround.

```js
// form validation
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('form .form-control').keyup(function () {
    let formBtn = true;
        $(this).each(function () {

            if ($(this).val().length === 0) {
                $(this).closest('.form-group').find('span').addClass('text-warning').text('this is a required field');
                formBtn = true;
            } else {
            formBtn = false;
                $(this).closest('.form-group').find('span').removeClass().text('');
                // CHECK IF EMAIL FORMAT IS VALID
                if ($(this).attr('name') == 'email') {
                    if (!validateEmail($(this).val())) {
                        $(this).closest('.form-group').find('span').addClass('text-warning').text('invalid email format');
                    }
                }

                if ($(this).attr('name') == 'name') {
                    if (!validateName($(this).val())) {
                        $(this).closest('.form-group').find('span').addClass('text-warning').text('Only letters, spacing, hypen(-) and period are allowed.');
                    }
                }

                if ($(this).attr('name') == 'contactNumber') {
                    if (!validateContactNumber($(this).val())) {
                        $(this).closest('.form-group').find('span').addClass('text-warning').text('Only Numbers are allowed.');
                    } else if (validateContactNumber($(this).val()) == "invalidLength") {
                        $(this).closest('.form-group').find('span').addClass('text-warning').text('9-15 numbers are allowed.');
                    }
                }
            }
    $(this).closest('form').find('button').prop('disabled',formBtn);
        });
    });


    // VALIDATE NAME
    function validateName(name) {
        var regex = /^[a-zA-Z-.\s]*$/;
        if (regex.test(name)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    // VALIDATE EMAIL
    function validateEmail(email) {
        var regex = /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@([A-Z0-9-]+\.)+[A-Z]{2,4}$/i;
        if (regex.test(email)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    // VALIDATE PHONE NUMBER
    function validateContactNumber(number) {
        var numValid = /^[0-9]+$/;
        var lenValid = /^.{9,15}$/;
        if (numValid.test(number)) {
            if (lenValid.test(number)) {
                return true;
            }else{
                return 'invalidLength';
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

```css
label{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 6px;
    letter-spacing: .025em;
    color: #2A363B;
}
.form-group span{
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 11px;
}
.form-control{
    padding: 12px 25px 12px 25px !important;
    line-height: 24px !important;
    border-radius: 0;
    font-weight: 400;
    height: auto;
    border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
    box-shadow: none;
    transition: .3s ease-in-out;
    background-color: #fcfcfc;
    color: #2A363B;
}
.form-control:focus {
    border-color: rgba(30, 30, 40, .5);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 4px rgba(30, 30, 40, .3);
}
.btn{
    padding: 14px 30px;
    border-radius: 0;
}
.btn-default{
    background-color: #2A363B;
    border: 1px solid #2A363B;
    color: #FFF;
    transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}
.btn-default:focus,
.btn-default:hover{
    background-color: #2A363B;
    border: 1px solid #2A363B;
    color: #FFF;
    opacity: 0.7 !important;
}
.btn[disabled]{
    background-color: #FFF;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    color: #222;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-6">
        <form class="form-horizontal" autocomplete="off" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="subject" class="control-label">Subject</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="subject" name="subject" required>
                <span></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name" class="control-label">Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" required>
                <span></span>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="email" class="control-label">Email</label>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" required>
                        <span></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="contactNumber" class="control-label">Contact Number</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="contactNumber" name="contactNumber" required>
                        <span></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="message" class="control-label">Message</label>
                <textarea name="message" id="message" cols="30" rows="10" class="form-control" name="message" required></textarea>
                <span></span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-4">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-block" name="contactBtn" disabled >SUBMIT</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```